# Is it possible to make an iterator in Lua that can iterate over a dictionary?

Tags: lua, iteration, lua-table, listiterator

Lets say that I have a dictionary in Lua (i.e. a Lua table that contains indexes of type string) like so:

```
local my_dictionary = {a = 123; b = 321; c = 456; d = 654};
```

What I am trying to do is create an iterator function that can iterate over a table even if its indexes are of type string; kind of like pairs, however whenever I try to call next() to get the next index,value it will only return the index,value if the index is of type int. An idea I had was maybe to call (index):byte(1, -1) and add up the tuple of ints, and use that as a sort of pretend index, just to keep track of the indexes, but I do not think that would work with next. Here is basically what I have so far:

```
local function each(list)
    if #list > 0 then
        local function my_itr(lst, ind)
            return next(lst, ind);
        end
        return my_itr, List, 0;
    end
    return function() end, nil, nil;
end
```

this only works for a table with int indexes (an array table), so I was wondering if anyone could help me out.
Thanks.
Edit: To make this less vague here is an example piece of code of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
local mytable = {a = 123; b = 321; 3, 2, 1, c = "bca"};
for i,v in each(mytable) do
    print(i,v);
end
```

what it should output:

```
>a 123
>b 321
>1 3
>2 2
>3 1
>c bca
```

The output would not have to be in exact order.

Comment: Your question is rather hard to understand. I can *guess* that you want to iterate string keys in lexicographical order, but still - could you please post an example of what you want to achieve, i.e. a table, a piece of code and the desired output?

Comment: Of course, I just edited it; Thanks

Comment: You say above that you only want to return int indexes, but your intended output shows behavior identical to `pairs()`. Which is it? BTW, this page shows how to implement `pairs`: https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work exactly as you want it to with a couple of tweaks: fix typo in `List` and pass `nil` instead of `0`:

```
local function each(list)
  local function my_itr(lst, ind)
    return next(lst, ind)
  end
  return my_itr, list, nil
end

local mytable = {a = 123; b = 321; 3, 2, 1, c = "bca"}
for i,v in each(mytable) do
  print(i,v)
end
```

This prints the following for me, which is what you'd need:

```
1   3
2   2
3   1
a   123
b   321
c   bca
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this very behavior by using `pairs`. Don't confuse it with `ipairs` though - these are two different table traversal functions!

While `ipairs` only traverses integer keys of the table (usually it also stops at the first non-existent integer key), `pairs` traverses **all** key-value pairs in the table.

So, by writing

```
local mytable = {a = 123; b = 321; 3, 2, 1, c = "bca"};
for i, v in pairs(mytable) do
    print(i, v);
end
```

You'll get all key-value pairs printed, in some random order. Here's the [demo](https://repl.it/JKqQ/0).

As a sidenote, there's no such thing as 'dictionary' in Lua - all associative arrays are referred to as 'tables'.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, and I hope that this doesn't sound rude, but that does not answer my question; I am knowledgeable of the pairs iterator factory; I am trying to make my own iterator that functions similar to pairs. Thank you for helping though.

Comment: Not rude at all. So, your goal is simply to re-implement `pairs`? OK then. Does it include re-implementing `next`? :)

Comment: Well at first I was only trying to re-implement pairs; But now that you mentioned next, I guess if I really wanted to re-implement pairs I would also have to re-implement next, but I am not sure if you can re-implement next without going into some C code.

Comment: @mikebayko no, you can't. Believe me :)

Comment: Well theoretically you COULD re-implement next, although you would have to make a system that matches every single possible string pattern that could be a key inside table, and check if it the key has a value inside table or not; It would be kind of like a rainbow table, except I do not think that it would run very well on computers; It would also probably take too long to complete a full sequence, if it didn't already crash the current program. :(